# Laravel authentication Not Working for a specific user

Tags: php, laravel, react-native

i have a code that works perfectly for login for every mobile users,until a user tries to login but he cant here is the login code,
Note, this happens to only this user

```
public function MobileLogin(Request $request)
{
    error_log($request);

    $n = $request->get('username');
    $p = $request->get('password');

    error_log($p);
    error_log($n);
    error_log('i got the values');

    if (Auth::attempt( array(
            'UserName' => $request->get('username'),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ) )) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $id = Auth::id();
        error_log($id); // i am able to see this value on the log which means user is authenticated

        $n = 'ok';

        return Response::json($user); // but i couldn't get this instead
    } else {
        $n ='Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again'; // i get this

        return Response::json($n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `UserName` set as a unique field in the database? If it isn't there could be two users with the same `UserName` causing this to fail.

Comment: THanks for the feed back,i found the error, the error was from the app, not laravel, thanks again.